# Does content in a jQuery ui tab get indexed if closed by default?

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, seo

I have a site that has a lot of traffic coming from the alt text in images.  I want to have Jquery UI tabs tabs with info, images, and contact.  I'd have the info open by default but the images in a closed jQuery UI tab.  Will the the images lose any SEO / indexing power?  Right now they're visible on the page without any tabs.  Would content in closed tabs by default be indexed the same as if it were fully visible on the page?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really shouldn't have an impact on the indexing power of the images. The search engines will only use the outputted html-code. They won't actually look if the text in the html is visible to the end user or not (Although they will punish you if they notice you abuse this by placing invisible text onto your website to get a better placement).